# MySQL count occurrences of a word in rows

Tags: mysql, count

I have a MySQL database that I am using as a register (ie person A was here, person B was not etc...) which is over several days.

I would like to determine how many times each person was present, so essentially count the number of times the word "Present" occurs in one row.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Read up about normalization to get the DB design right.

Comment: juergen d - I do know about normalisation, how would you suggest this is fully normalised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a normalized table design with these tables

```
persons table
-------------
id
name
...


registration table
------------------
person_id
date
status
```

Then you can count how many days a person was present, for instance in the current week, like this

```
select sum(status = 'present') as present_days
from persons p
join registration r on r.person_id = p.id
where yearweek(r.date) = yearweek(curdate())
and p.name = 'tom'
```

Comment: Thanks Juergen that's really helpful! I hadn't considered doing it like that!